# Why does my YouTube React component fire the PlayerState.ENDED event twice before playing the next video?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube-api

I have a React component which renders and controls an embedded YouTube player using the YouTube Iframe API. The parent component manages a queue of videos and passes the first item in the queue to the player to be played.

Once the first video in the queue finishes playing, the `handleStateChange()` method is called as expected and I can see that the `PlayerState.ENDED` event has been fired. I then call the `onVideoEnd()` callback to notify the parent component that it should play the next video in the queue.

The problem I'm having is when the second video is queued via the `player.loadVideoById()` function it fires a second `PlayerState.ENDED` event. This causes the parent to remove yet another video from the queue, effectively skipping the freshly queued video.

Can anyone see an obvious reason why this is happening? I've verified that the API script is only loaded once, so I don't think that's the issue.

Here's a codesandbox demonstrating this behavior: https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-smoke-8d7zj

It's easiest to see the problem in the console when you queue 3 videos.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

The solution seemed to be a combination of disabling autoplay and seeking to 0 seconds before playing the next video.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const { player } = this.state;
  const { video } = this.props;

  if (video && prevProps.video !== video) {
    console.log("componentDidUpdate");

    player.seekTo(0);

    player.loadVideoById({
      videoId: video.id,
      startSeconds: video.startSeconds,
      endSeconds: video.endSeconds
    });
  }
}

...

render() {
  return (
    <iframe
      title="ytplayer"
      style={{ display: "block" }}
      id="ytplayer"
      type="text/html"
      width="720"
      height="405"
      src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/NeKXvINnk04?enablejsapi=1`} // remove "&autoplay=1"
      frameBorder="0"
      allowFullScreen
    />
  );
}
```

I suspect if I truly wanted to use the autoplay option I would need to use the `player.cueVideoById()` function instead of `player.loadVideoById()`.

Comment: ```player.seekTo(0);``` helped here!